# Find prime numbers. Prime number form other then 6k+1 6k-1

Tags: c, math, primes

I'm trying to optimize a prime search algorithm.

I have a program that finds (counts actually) primes below some limit. I know that prime number can be expressed in form `6k+1`, `6k-1`, for some `k > 0`.

For time present I use sieving algorithm to sort non-primes out. Some pseudo code :

```
int P[100] = {1};
int m = 100;
int n = 2, k, i, j, sqrtm = (int)sqrt(m);
for(k = 2, i = 5; i < sqrtm + 1; i += k, k ^= 6)
 if(P[i])
  P[i] = 0;
  n = n + 1;
  for(j = i * i; j < m; j += 2 * i)
   P[j] = 0;

for(k = 2, i = 5; i < m + 1; i += k, k ^= 6)
 if(P[i])n = n + 1;

print n;
```

Above code hopefully prints number of primes below number m.
I'm using some tricks here and there to speed things up. For example, starting sieving non-primes from '5', use the fact, that prime number in above form can't be multiples of '2' and '3'. 6k + 2 is even. 6k + 3 is multiple of '3', let x = 2k, 6k + 3 => 3x + 3 => 3(x + 1) mod 3 == 0, or 3(2k + 1) mod 3 == 0.

Here, my question arises. If I make a pre-sieve with some primes, can I take a different form of prime number to speed up sieving loop ? 
For example, pre-sieve with 2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29. So, now P array has no multiples of of above. Maybe one can suggest me some form of prime number form, such, that with pre-sieving, loop can be done is larger chunks.

I've already done some, non related to prime number form, optimizations. Like sieving in chunks and using bit set to store sieve. All that made my program to run pretty fast.

```
time ./np 1000000000
allocated 119Mb
primes from 2 <= 1000000000 : 50847534

real    0m2.386s
user    0m2.354s
sys 0m0.032s
```

I know I can get better prime number counter program from the internet. And it will run faster. But I just want to know how far I can go by myself. And community help ;)

To sum things up. I want to use a pre-sieving. I think that it gets me less comparisons plus less inner loops total. I ask you, how to write prime number in other form, knowing the pre-sieving fact?

Comment: The `k ^= 6` notation is unusual; are you sure it does what you think it does?

Comment: "with pre-sieving, loop can be done is larger chunks" please rephrase or explain, I do not get that.

Comment: What Jonathan wants to tell (I bet, otherwise please correct me @Jonathan) is to read up on what the operator `^` or `^=` actually does n C.

Comment: @Amessihel So much comments about clarification. Maybe I really should post some code.

Comment: I think you will get diminishing value from increasing the step size above 6.  Is it worth the extra complexity to increase the speed 2% or so?

Comment: You can go with multiples of 2 * 3 ± 1 (as now; or, equivalently, 2 * 3 + { 1, 5 }), or 2 * 3 * 5 + { 1, ..., 29 }, or 2 * 3 * 5 * 7 + { 1, …, 209 }, or ... but the extra overhead in those lists is considerable and probably not worth it.  You'd probably do as well with a tqble of primes to 1000 or so, and then go multiples of 6 ± 1 from there.  It depends, in part, on how big the values you're working with.  If you're dealing with 200-digit primes, then you start looking at probabilistic methods — but you also don't count the number of primes less than the value.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler 2 is 0010 in binary. 4 is 0100 in binary. 6 is 0110 in binary. So, starting from n = 2, 0010 xor 0110 = 0100 = 4. 0100 xor 0110 = 0010 = 2. So basically k ^= 6 loops from 2 to 4.

Comment: Prime sieving works by ruling out composites, but composites, by nature, a products of multiple (not necessarily distinct) primes, so sieves tend to visit composites more than once each.  Reducing the average number of times each composite is visited tends to increase performance, but that is offset by any increases in the cost of each visit.  Your approach makes exactly such a tradeoff.

Comment: @Yunnosch I got wrong wording. Loop is done in same step, it is comparison with sieve array that makes loop skip its step.

Comment: @stark I need to time that. If it speed things up, then maybe it is worth it. I can't wait 10min to see my 10^12 result ;)

Comment: @Amessihel Yes, presieving skips composite number after one basic comparison(bit set check).

Comment: @ЯрославМашко: I see what the `k ^= 6` does now.  It's a clever, but probably not easily generalized.  That is, I don't think you'd find an analogous trick when the increment was 30 (2 * 3 * 5) or 210 (2 * 3 * 5 * 7), or beyond.

Comment: You might want to read up on [Wheel factorisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_factorization) for more ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say that, other than `2` and `3`, all prime numbers have the form `2*3*k±1` (for some integer k>=1)

You can extend that to

2*3*5*k ±{1, 7, 11, 13} (and 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13)

or

2*3*5*7*k ±{1, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109} (and 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97)

Implementing this forms may not make your program more efficient (however you define efficient). You need to measure.

<sup>Values above were typed directly from mobile **without** validation. Use at your own risk.</sup>

Comment: Please explain what does those numbers in round brackets mean. (2,3,5,7,11,13).

Comment: My point is such, that if I pre-sieve with all primes below 2*3*5, I can get loop step bigger. So, in my thoughts, I have numbers in form 30k ± {1, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29}.

Comment: It's interesting that the list of numbers to add/subtract is symmetric.  The list in parentheses, @ЯрославМашко, is a list of prime numbers that you also need to check.  Basically, primes smaller than `2 * 3 * 5 - 13` need to be checked specially.  There is considerable structure in those lists — the terms are all prime numbers, and 1; and the smallest prime number is the one after the largest prime in the product of the initial primes.  So, if you used `2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11`, you'd check ± 1, ± 13, etc.

Comment: So we have: 6k ± 1 is like 1/3 of total visits. 30k + {1, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29} is like 8/30 ~ 1/4 of total visits. P.S i meant 30k _plus_ {..} in above comment.

Comment: Yes, that's right.  The more contiguous prime numbers in the `2 * 3 * 5 * …` list you have, the fewer extra composites you check, but the bigger the list of numbers to be checked.  The question is whether the overhead is worth the saving.  As I said in another comment (to the main question), it depends on what you're going to be doing (how big the primes are) — and how often you'll be doing it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I thought about your comments for a while. Indeed its is quite interesting that the numbers to add/subtract is symmetric. Did not notice the fact, I could not understand why I have to check not a whole set of prime numbers that are less then 30, but only half of it. Now I see why I have to check only 2,3,5,7,11,13 for 30k ± {1, 7, 11, 13}. Interesting fact, before that I was going to check all prime terms.

Comment: I had to leave SO for a while, sorry. Thanks to @JonathanLeffler to explain my meaning.

Comment: Note that for multipliers 6 (2 * 3), 30 (2 * 3 * 5), and 210 (2 * 3 * 5 * 7), the list of additives are all primes.  However, when you get to 2310 (2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11), the additives include some non-prime (composite) numbers; the smallest such composite additive is 169 (13*13), and the smallest prime which corresponds is 2141, which is 2310 - 169.  Beware of finding formulae with primes; they often break down.